# Error Message and Validate Data in ASPX form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I need to validate a textbox value, to ensure it is contain numbers only and I need to display two error message. When the textbox is null and when the input is not in numeric. I want to use regular expression to validate the input. Minimum length of password is 8. This is my code:

```
<div class="col1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col2">Password</div>
<div class="col3">:</div>
<div class="col4">
    <asp:TextBox ID="passgen" CssClass="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" TabIndex="1" MaxLength="8"/>&nbsp;
    <span class="clsRed">*</span>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
function validate() {
    var PassGen = document.getElementById('<%=passgen.ClientID %>').value;
    if (PassGen == "") {
        alert("Password is empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to change my code to reach the requirement and which regular expression should I use? I'm using visual studio 2012, ASPX web form and C#.

Comment: Have you tried using the aspx validators?

Comment: You mean <asp:RegularExpressionValidator /> ? Can it use to show two error message? One for null value and one for wrong input. @Aishaterr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple validators for a single control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="passgen" CssClass="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" TabIndex="1" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passgen" ErrorMessage="Cannot be null" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers only" ControlToValidate="passgen" ValidationExpression=@"^\d+?$" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passgen" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Display="Dynamic" Type="Integer" SetFocusOnError="true"  ValueToCompare="8" ErrorMessage="Minimum of 8 characters"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: tq, for that answer. @aishaterr

Comment: @Syafah No worries mate. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, you could use pattern to validate the amount of characters and required would solve the problem when the field is empty

```
<asp:TextBox ID="passgen" CssClass="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" TabIndex="1"  
 pattern=".{8,}" required  title="More than eight characters"   />
```